# How do I add a speed option that text is displayed at?

Tags: python

Hi I'm working on a text adventure game and wanted to see if someone could help me with how I would add an option to how quick text is displayed along the screen. Below is what I thought I would do but honestly I got no idea. So if someone picked slow how would i get slow to be used throughout the whole thing.

```
from time import *

textSpeed = input("From the following speeds pick which one you would like to use. [slow/medium/fast] ")


if textSpeed == "slow":
    def slowReading():
        sleep(7)
elif textSpeed == "medium":
    def mediumReading():
        sleep(6)
elif textSpeed == "fast":
    def fastReading():
        sleep(5)


print("Welcome to my game") 
#The text speed they pick would be here

'''
```

Comment: You need to do a [basic tutorial on Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). `def` defines a function which probably doesn't make sense here.